# How to get the value of annotation using Reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How can I get the value of the annotation using Java `Reflection` ?

This is the annotated method:

```
@JsonView( { View.class } )
public Element getElement()
{
    return element;
}
```

Comment: Have you spent any time looking this up? This is pretty trivial to do in Java, and there are examples all over the web.

Comment: To get the value of an annotation is to use getAnnotation. They couldn't have made it simpler AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the some way to get annotation,

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);

    cls.getDeclaredAnnotations(); // get all annotation
    (cls.getDeclaredMethods()[0]).getAnnotations(); //get annotation of a method
    Annotation ety = cls.getAnnotation(Annotation.class); // get annotation of particular annotation class
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that your method is declared in class `MyClass`, do the following:

```
MyClass.class.getMethod("getElement").getAnnotation(JsonView.class).value()
```

Comment: there is no `value()` method on `Annotation`

Comment: @AlexBurdusel [`getAnnotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) is a generic method, and `@JsonView` must declared a `value()` method for it to be used in the way that's shown in the question body.