# Extract @Nullable/@NonNull annotations of given method handle

Tags: java, checker-framework

I am playing around with the CheckerFramework and wanted to extract the effective @Nullable/@NonNull annotations of the return value and parameters of a method, e.g. `some.package.Thing: Object compute(Object,Collection)`. The only way I found so far, is to generate source code that uses this method in different nullness contexts, so that I can infer the annotations from the checker results. But I am pretty sure that there is a way to extend the NullnessChecker, so that I can give it a method handle (obtained through reflection) of method on the classpath and export the effective nullness annotations. Can anybody give me some hints on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As background, the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) lets you write annotations on types, such as `List<@NonNull String>`, but it also applies [defaulting and inference](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#effective-qualifier).

The final type annotation is written to the class file.
Therefore, you can use tools that read the class file.

- `javap -v MyFile.class` will show you a lot of information including the type annotations.
- The [Annotation File Utilities](https://checkerframework.org/annotation-file-utilities/) read annotations from, and write annotations to, `.java` files, `.class` files, and text files.  This is what I would use, but I am not sure of your use case.  I would compile the `.java` file, then run [`extract-annotations mypackage.MyClass`](https://checkerframework.org/annotation-file-utilities/#extract-annotations) to create a text file `mypackage.MyClass.jaif`.  A human or a tool can read that file.
- If the annotations have run-time retention (most annotations, such as [`@Nullable`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html), do), you can also obtain them via reflection.  This requires you to load the class under analysis, however.  You can see a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html) or [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340666/how-to-get-the-value-of-annotation-using-reflection-in-java).

Comment: I have looked at jaif files before, but I wasn't sure if all annotations, including those of inherited methods, are flattened there. E.g. if the class `A` defines a method as `@Nullable Object m()`, will the same annotation be in the jaif of an inheriting class `B`, which does not override this method? In other words, does the jaif of a class represent the complete facts known about this class? Also, are all nullable annotations flattened to `@Nullable` or `@NonNull`, or is the parameters defaults of the package etc. need to be examined for a correct inference from jaif?

Comment: What I need in essence, is an oracle that I can ask for the effective nullness annotations of a method, so that this oracle would yield the exact same results as if I was checking code that is using this method. The NullnessChecker does a lot of inference, so I am unsure if the jaifs can actually serve for this purpose.

Comment: Per the second paragraph of section [The effective qualifier on a type (defaults and inference)](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#effective-qualifier), "the .class file contains the explicit or defaulted annotations from the source code".  It sounds like that is what you want.  `javap` and reflection read annotations from the same place (the `.class` file).

Comment: [Currently](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/286), declaration annotations are inherited from overridden methods, but type annotations are not.  The Checker Framework prompts the user to write them, which makes the source code more explicit.