# How to make sure the @Scheduled annotation is present on the method

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing, scheduler

In our `Spring Boot` application, we have a method with a `@Scheduled` annotation:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L * 60 * 10, initialDelay = 1000L * 60 * 5)
   public void doSomethingFromTimeToTime(){....}
```

During our maven build testing phase, we like to make sure that:

1. annotation is there (e.g. was not removed by mistake by a developer) and
2. contains these exact values

Is there a way to somehow test this in unit/integration tests? or in another mean during the build phase?

We don't need to test the Spring's Scheduler itself, just to make sure the annotation is there.

Comment: Hi @riorio, would you by any chance be looking for [Class#getAnnotation()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class))? Once you have the `Annotation` object, you can check indvidual properties on it with the provided getters.

Comment: @PaulBenn this was exactly what I needed. would you like to add an answer for the kudos?

Comment: Glad I could help. One second, I'll add it as answer so other people can benefit too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test an annotation is present on a `Class` object using the [`.getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)) method of the `Class`, where `A` is a generic type parameter just as `T` usually is.

Example usage:

```
Scheduled scheduledAnnotation = MySpringScheduler.class.getAnnotation(Scheduled.class).
```

After you have the annotation, you can access the fields using the annotation's provided methods just like you would on a normal class:

```
scheduledAnnotation.fixedDelay();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this way you can get it easily using reflection

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);

    cls.getDeclaredAnnotations(); // get all annotation
    (cls.getDeclaredMethods()[0]).getAnnotations(); //get annotation of a method
    Annotation ety = cls.getAnnotation(Annotation.class); // get annotation of particular annotation class
```

ref [How to get the value of annotation using Reflection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340666/how-to-get-the-value-of-annotation-using-reflection-in-java)